# How to save Json Array into HTML format in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, rake-task

Hello Ruby users i have Json Array format

```
[
"Can also work with any bluetooth-enabled smartphones and\ntablets",
 "For calls and music, Hands-free", 
"Very stylish design and lightweight", 
"Function:Bluetooth,Noise Cancelling,Microphone", 
"Compatible:For Any Device With Bluetooth Function", 
"Chipset: CSR4.0", "Bluetooth Version:Bluetooth 4.0", 
"Transmission Distance:10 Meters"
]
```

I want to save this array into html formal using the html format which is below.

```
<ul>
    <li>Can also work with any bluetooth-enabled smartphones and\ntablets</li> 
    <li>For calls and music, Hands-free</li> 
    <li>Very stylish design and lightweight</li> 
    <li>Function:Bluetooth,Noise Cancelling,Microphone</li> 
    <li>Compatible:For Any Device With Bluetooth Function</li> 
    <li>Chipset: CSR4.0</li> 
    <li>Bluetooth Version:Bluetooth 4.0</li> 
    <li>Transmission Distance:10 Meters</li>
</ul>
```

This is my current code which is working correctly if i have to save it just the array however i need this to be html format so user can easily read it

```
result = JSON.parse(jsonparse)

result["mods"]["listItems"].each do |result|
    @item = Item.new
    @item.item_details = result["description"]

    @item.save
end
```

**Under my Previous Attempt to solve like this**

```
result = JSON.parse(jsonparse)

result["mods"]["listItems"].each do |result|
    @item = Item.new

    item_list = result["description"]
    item_list.each do |list|
      @item.item_details = "<li>"+list+"</li>"
    end

    @item.save
end
```

This one only save one of the array and no `<ul>` head

heres the original code

```
namespace :scraper do
  desc "Scrape Website"
  task somesite: :environment do

    require 'open-uri'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'json'

        url = "url here!"
        page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
        script = page.search('head script')[2]

        jsonparse = script.content[/\{\"[a-zA-Z0-9\"\:\-\,\ \=\(\)\.\_\D\/\[\]\}]+/i]

        result = JSON.parse(jsonparse)

        result["mods"]["listItems"].each do |result|
            @item = Item.new


            item_details = result["description"].each {|list| "<li>#{list}</li>" }
            puts item_details

            @item.item_old_price = result["originalPrice"]
            @item.item_final_price = result["price"]

            @item.save
        end
  end
end
```

The Idea is to save the Array into database with the html format.

```
    <ul>
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2</li>
    <li>content and soon</li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: should one `Item` store the entire HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure about your questions. @Anthony
There are many data but my primary focus is the `item_details` since its the only data that has arrays. that's why I don't need to put all other data which is not relevant to the question. hope that clarify things for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you tried to do.

Please check below codes and give me a feedback.
Happy coding :)

```
<!-- language: ruby -->
require 'json'

class MyJsonParser
  def initialize
    @items = []
  end

  def parse(json)
    result = JSON.parse(json)
    generate_items(result)

    items
  end

  private

  attr_reader :items

  def generate_items(result)
    result['mods']['listItems'].each {|item_detail| items << Item.new(item_detail)}
  end
end

class Item
  attr_reader :details

  def initialize(detail='')
    @details = ''
    before_initialize
    details << detail
    after_initialize
  end

  private

  def before_initialize
    details << '<li>'
  end

  def after_initialize
    details << '</li>'
  end
end

json_str = '{
  "mods": {
    "listItems":
      [
        "Can also work with any bluetooth-enabled smartphones and\ntablets",
        "For calls and music, Hands-free",
        "Very stylish design and lightweight",
        "Function:Bluetooth,Noise Cancelling,Microphone",
        "Compatible:For Any Device With Bluetooth Function",
        "Chipset: CSR4.0",
        "Bluetooth Version:Bluetooth 4.0",
        "Transmission Distance:10 Meters"
      ]
  }
}'

result = MyJsonParser.new.parse(json_str)
result.each do |i|
  p i.details
end
```